# Using undefined variable or array offset as argument in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a static method that returns or creates an object if it doesn't exist. I'd like to find an elegant way to handle passing an ID argument to the object.

The logic here is that if an ID is passed, the object is created with that ID. If not, it's created with a default ID.

What I had was:

```
class App {
    private $game_obj;

    public static function get_game ($arguments) {
    if (!isset($this->game_obj))
            $this->game_obj = new Game ($arguments[0]);

    return $this->game_obj;
    }
}

class Game {
    private $gameID;

    public function __construct ($id=1) {
        $this=>gameID = $id;
        /* other code */
    }
}
```

When I call `App::get_game(5)` I get the result I expect. A Game object with a gameID of 5.

When I call `App::get_game()` I *do not* get the result I expect, which would be a Game object with a gameID of 1. Instead I get an error about undefined offset in the `App::get_game ()`.

I updated `App::get_game()` as follows, but it seems particularly inelegant. I'd prefer to define the default ID in the class definition.

```
class App {
    private $game_obj;

    public static function get_game ($arguments) {
    if (!isset($this->game_obj)) {
            $default_id = 1; // I don't like having this here
            $id = isset ($arguments[0] ? $arguments[0] : $default_id;
            $this->game_obj = new Game ($id);
        }

    return $this->game_obj;
    }
}
```

Is there a simpler/better/more elegant way to handle this? Ideally one that would keep my default ID declaration in the Game class itself?

Comment: You are passing in a scalar `5` but your method expects `$arguments` is an array.

Comment: I don't know if this is really any more elegant but you could move the ternary operation to the get_game static method so your above code we be as is, but when you create the Game object on line 5, you do something like this:  $this->game_obj = new Game (isset($arguments[0]) ? $arguments[0] : 1);

Answer (score 0):

did you try

```
public static function get_game ($arguments=null) {
if($arguments==null) //etc..
```

?

Answer (score 0):

you can test with :

```
if(is_object($my_object)) {

    }
```